# how to manipulate a list of properties in a class when sending one email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to implement order confirmation in application (MVC 4) which uses a shopping cart.
I'm at the stage where I want to send out an email to both the customer and Admin user to confirm the order.
I want to send one email for one order(Cart).
My Cart class.

I have a Cart Model:

```
  namespace MerchandiseProject.Domain.Entities
 {
      public class Cart
      {
        private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();

        public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity) 
        {
        CartLine line = lineCollection
        .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
        .FirstOrDefault();
            if (line == null)
            {
                lineCollection.Add(new CartLine { Product = product,
                Quantity = quantity });
            }
        else 
            {
                line.Quantity += quantity;
            }
       }

        public void RemoveLine(Product product)
        {
            lineCollection.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
        }

        public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
        {
            return lineCollection.Sum(e => e.Product.Price * e.Quantity);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            lineCollection.Clear();
        }

        public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines 
        {
            get { return lineCollection; }
        }

     }

      public class CartLine
      {
          public Product Product { get; set; }
          public int Quantity { get; set; }
      }
  }
```

I am passing this model and the shipping details model back to POST checkout actionResult in my Cartcontroller and assigning their values to an Orders class, these details are also persisted to the database.
The information being past back to the database are correct.
But how to extract it in the likes of a "foreach" statement has me stuck !

Orders Class:

```
 namespace MerchandiseProject.Domain.Entities
 {
public class Orders
{
    private List<OrderLine> lineCollection = new List<OrderLine>();
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public bool GiftWrap { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderLine> Lines
    {
        get { return lineCollection; }
    }
}
    public class OrderLine
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

My problem is in my Cart Controller Checkout ViewResult [POST], an email goes out for every type of product in the cart, I want to send **one** e-mail with the list of products ordered ? make sense ?

Cart Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Checkout(Cart cart, ShippingDetails shippingDetails)
    {
        var CurrentUser = HttpContext.User;
        string currentUserName = CurrentUser.Identity.Name;
        if (cart.Lines.Count() == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sorry, your cart is empty!");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var line in cart.Lines)
            {
                var model = new Orders()
                {
                    ProductName = line.Product.Name,
                    ProductUnitPrice = line.Product.Price,
                    Quantity = line.Quantity,
                    OrderTotal = line.Quantity * line.Product.Price,
                    UserName = currentUserName,
                    Name = shippingDetails.Name,
                    Line1 = shippingDetails.Line1,
                    Line2 = shippingDetails.Line2,
                    Line3 = shippingDetails.Line3,
                    City = shippingDetails.City,
                    State = shippingDetails.State,
                    Country = shippingDetails.Country,
                    GiftWrap = shippingDetails.GiftWrap,
                    OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Zip = shippingDetails.Zip,
                };
                new MailController(_actionMailer).OrderDetailsEmail(model).Deliver();
            }
            orderProcessor.SaveOrder(currentUserName ,cart, shippingDetails);
            cart.Clear();
            return View("Completed");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(shippingDetails);
        }
    }
```

Please note - asp.net MVC 4 using razor views.

Comment: Move your call to the `Mailcontroller` out of the `foreach` loop?

Comment: If I do that the var model is not picked up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DStanley said, you are literally saying to send an email for each line item by having your `MailController` line within the foreach loop. If the problem is you need access to `model` outside the context of the foreach loop, then you need to persist it in a variable in a parent scope. For example:

```
var lineItems = new List<Order>();
foreach (var line in cart.Lines)
{
    lineItems.Add(new Order
    {
        ...
    });
}
```

However, if you're going to do that, it's more efficient to just use `Select`:

```
var lineItems = cart.Lines.Select(m => new Order
{
    ProductName = m.Product.Name,
    ...
});
```

Removing the need for the `foreach` completely.

Comment: So replace the foreach and var model code for the above and replace model in the MailController line with ...? if I insert "LineItems", I'll need to change the OrderDetailsEmail to accept IEmunerable ??

Comment: That's all implementation details. The idea here is that you do have a multiple "things" you want to pass to your email. However, you could restructure the code to have some class that contains the line item enumerable and just pass that single object in, or yes, you could change the way the email function works, but that's entirely up to you and the needs of your application.

Comment: The less changing the better,not sure I quite follow how the last comment .... in order to pass an Orders model to the Mailcontroller ??

Comment: The point is that no one can answer that for you. You wanted to know how to not send an email for each line item and instead send just one for the whole order. You have your answer: move the email sending code outside the context of a loop where the scope is an individual line item and into a scope where all the line items are available. How you use that data and the exact form your code may take is up to you and outside the purview of this question.